# Adding border to masked image in sketch

Tags: shapes, sketch-app, mask

I am currently in the process of trying to cut part of a circle while still displaying the full image that is masked. It might be easier to show an example.

I am trying to do something like this:

[image]

This is what I have:

[image]

But I'm not really sure how to get that same effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a border to the image.

To add a border to a masked image: 
Select the mask from the layers in the left side bar to show the "Borders" section in the right sidebar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you've got here is a white stroke applied to the images. There's no need to "cut out" any part of the images.

Here's the link to the borders page of the sketch docs [link](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/08-styling/2-borders.html)

Then just re arrange the images on top of each other to get this cut out effect.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here looking for a way to add a border to a masked image...

In fairness to the OP, there may be a good reason for masking the image (non destructively editing the image and mask separately), and I don't seem to be able to see a Border which is applied to the mask or the masked image, when the edges of the image are cropped off by the mask.

A solution is to duplicate the mask and drag it above the masked image, and 'Ignore Underlying Mask'. Borders can then be applied to the new layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to set the border on the mask to outside. That way, the picture is not covering the mask, and you get to dynamically adjust stroke and color.